# Android CursorWrapperInner: Cursor finalized without prior close()

Tags: android, cursor

in my application i keep getting this warning in my log:

```
12-17 20:17:20.979: W/CursorWrapperInner(3715): Cursor finalized without prior close().
```

when using:

```
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
.detectAll()
.penaltyLog()
.penaltyDeath()
.build());
```

i get:

```
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.<init>(ContentResolver.java:1582)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:321)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.android.AndroidConfig.getSetting(AndroidConfig.java:216)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.android.AndroidConfig.getDistributionChannelInternal(AndroidConfig.java:195)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.Config.init(Config.java:273)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.android.AndroidConfig.<init>(AndroidConfig.java:100)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.common.android.AndroidConfig.<init>(AndroidConfig.java:87)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at com.google.android.maps.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:419)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at com.WhosAround.Activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:36)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at com.WhosAround.Activities.Loader.onCreate(Loader.java:64)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-17 20:19:55.049: E/StrictMode(3919):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the application actually crashes...
how can i debug where this warning is coming from ?
i'm not using any Cursor that i know of...

Comment: the issue is in mapActivity rather than your app

Comment: What's happening on line 36 in BaseActivity: `at com.WhosAround.Activities.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:36)`?

Comment: BaseActivity extends MapActivity and this line is the super.onCreate()

Comment: @nandeesh so what should i do ? i have no access to MapActivity

Comment: you cannot do anything, the problem is in maps.jar that comes with Android platform. You could change the avd to latest version and check once whether this has been fixed

Comment: the weirdest thing is that the error appear only in android 4.x and not in 2.3. any reason why is that ?

Comment: btw, is it a known issue ? i haven't found any information about it