# How to tell which android sqlite cursor variable is causing a warning or exception?

Tags: android, android-cursor

I have two related problems with cursors, and am having trouble identifying which cursors are causing the problem.

First, I'm trying to knock out all the LogCat messages about "Cursor finalized without prior close()".

I know why the message is printed, and I know how to fix the problem. What I can't figure out is the one last cursor that is not being closed. I've poured over the code multiple times, and as best I can tell, all are.

Second, is a onResume issue, where I get a "stale data: cursor closed, can't requery" exception. The stack trace is all internal to android.xx and com.android, so I can' tell which cursor is causing the problem. (I have some hunches, but nothing firm)

Is there a setting/flag I can poke to get the OS to tell me something more about these ? Details on the cursor (like what table it's associated with, the column set on it, etc), cursor variable name, line of code the cursor was allocated/declared on, etc ?

Or am I stuck stepping through a lot of code and cursors in the debugger, or is there another method to winnow this out that I haven't thought of ?

EDIT:

```
`StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
.detectAll()
.penaltyLog()
.penaltyDeath()
.build());`
```

Will force an crash/terminate on the un-closed cursors.
Via [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919790/android-cursorwrapperinner-cursor-finalized-without-prior-close?rq=1)

Comment: OK, found something that may help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919790/android-cursorwrapperinner-cursor-finalized-without-prior-close?rq=1) mentions how to force an exception under: `    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
.detectAll()
.penaltyLog()
.penaltyDeath()
.build());`